# page white with routing in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem in routing angular js , I use version 1.6.4 of angular js

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>authentification with Angular JS</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body class="container" ng-app="starter" >
    <a href="#!outside">Outside</a>
    <a href="#!outside.register">register</a>
    <a href="#!outside.login">Login</a>
    <a href="#!inside">Inside</a>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="service.js"></script>
    <script src="constants.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js:

```
var e = angular.module('starter',[])

e.config(function($routeProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/outside',{
        //url: '/outside',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'outside.html'
    })

    .when('/outside.login',{
        //url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })

    .when('/outside.register',{
        //url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })

    .when('/inside',{
        //url: '/inside',
        templateUrl: 'inside.html',
        controller: 'InsideCtrl'
    });

    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/outside/login');

}); 

e.run(function($rootScope,$state,AuthService,AUTH_EVENTS){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStar',function(event, next, nextParams, fromState){
        if(!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
            if (next.name !== 'outside.login' && next.name !== 'outside.register'){
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('outside.login');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

for example this is page login.html:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Login">Login</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
</div>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">Login</button> <br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ui-serf="outside.register">Register</button>
```

but when I clicked in link login for example I have any result, page is white

help me please for resolve this problem and thanks advanced

Comment: What errors are you getting? there is no `$state` in `ngRoute`. Should be seeing an injection error

Comment: I have any error in console

Comment: your code is confusing.  you have `ng-route` references and are using `ng-view`, but in other portions have `ui-serf` which isn't even valid and `$state` which is part of `ui-router`, not `ng-route`.  (in `ui-router`, it's `ui-sref`, not `ui-serf`, btw.).

Comment: also, you have a typo in your `e.run`;  there is no `'$stateChangeStar'` event.  You say that you have no errors in the console, but the code you posted would throw multiples.  It might be a good idea to proof read your question once more and make sure all the relevant pieces are listed.  see [mcve].

Comment: @Claies , what is your solution for resolve my code ??

Comment: are you using `ng-route` or `ui-router`?  some of your code suggests you are using one, some suggests the other, and you can't use both.

Comment: I use ng-route my friend

Comment: then the first thing you need to do is remove the parts of the code that have `ui-router` in them (`$state`, `ui-sref`, etc.) then post an updated version of your code if it is still broken.

Comment: @Claies , okey I remove $state in config and I use when and I remove ui-serf( I use them in button register ) , Now what do you want me to do !?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the *ngRoute* as a dependency. 
This line

```
var e = angular.module('starter',[])
```

should be

```
var e = angular.module('starter',['ngRoute']);
```

Here's a basic example

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "main.html"
        })
        .when("/test", {
            templateUrl : "test.html"
        })
        .when('/outside',{
            //url: '/outside',
            abstract: true
        })
        .when('/outside.login',{
            //url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            //controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/outside.register',{
            //url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'register.html',
            //controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>authentification with Angular JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  
    <a href="#/!">Main</a>
    <a href="#!test">test</a>
    
    <a href="#!outside.login">login</a>
    <a href="#!outside.register">register</a>
    
    <div ng-view></div>
  
  
  
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
      test
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
      main
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="login.html">
      login
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="register.html">
      register
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** *If you having trouble with a white page then most likely you have not specified the templateUrl correctly*

Comment: also problem white page and I edited my question when I add content page login.html

Comment: I update my code when I add ngRoute but also problem white page , this is my new code after update https://pastebin.com/rMXbzZ2x